# Joining 3 tables and matching null entries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables, users, news, news_viewed. I'm trying to join these 3 tables and find a list of news each user has not viewed.

- TABLE `users`

  - userid
  - username
  - status
- TABLE `news`

  - newsid
  - title
  - post_time
- TABLE `news_viewed`

  - nvid
  - username
  - newsid

Looking to find a list from `users` that have not read news (found in `news_viewed`)

I've tried many different joins, including left joins and inners and outers but cannot get the results I need.

```php
$_30daysago = strtotime('-30 days');
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT users.username, news_id 
    FROM users inner join news_viewed ON
    users.username = news_viewed.username and users.status='active'
    UNION
    SELECT news_viewed.username, post_time 
    FROM news_viewed inner join news ON
    news_viewed.newsid = news.newsid and news.post_time>'$_30daysago'
) as JoinedTable
```

I need the required results to include the users.username, news.newsid and news.title.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/39344/157408 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/25890534/2943403

Comment: Also, you don't need to pass the date variable in from php -- mysql has perfectly capable datetime functions for you to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a good spot to use the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern:

```
SELECT u.username, n.newsid, n.title
FROM users u
INNER JOIN news n ON n.post_time > ?
LEFT JOIN news_viewed nv 
    ON n.newsid = nv.newsid
    AND nv.username = u.username 
WHERE 
    u.status = 'active' 
    AND nv.nvid IS NULL
```

This query generates a cartesian product of users and recent news (ie having a post time greater than the parameter indicated by `?`), and returns the users/news tuples for which the left join on news_viewed did not succeed (hence the antipattern).

Note: it is unclear what column to use in the join; column name `news_viewed (username)` tend to indicate that it relates to `users(username)`, whereas the primary key of `users` seems to be `userid`. Fix your column names or fix your relationship.

Comment: Thank you, but table `news` must also be included to find what news is available. Then query `news_viewed` to see what user hasn't read.

Comment: @cr1to: I just added the `news` table to the query.

Comment: @cr1to: I thing I initially misread your question. I just updated my answer, let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ellaborating on @GMB's answer

Your query:

```
$_30daysago = strtotime('-30 days');
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT users.username, news_id 
    FROM users inner join news_viewed ON
    users.username = news_viewed.username and users.status='active'
    UNION
    SELECT news_viewed.username, post_time 
    FROM news_viewed inner join news ON
    news_viewed.newsid = news.newsid and news.post_time>'$_30daysago'
) as JoinedTable
```

is saying:

> get all active users with the news they have read (inner join)

```
SELECT users.username, news_id 
FROM users inner join news_viewed ON
users.username = news_viewed.username and users.status='active'
```

> and add all the news with the users that have read them in the last 30 days (inner join again)

```
SELECT news_viewed.username, post_time 
FROM news_viewed inner join news ON
news_viewed.newsid = news.newsid and news.post_time>'$_30daysago'
```

That is actually bringing up all the tuples from `news_viewed` minus the ones where the user is not active AND the new is over 30 days old.

however, given the usage of inner join, you're bringing a lot of duplicate records

1.- The results from the first query where the new is less than 30 days old

2.- The results from the second query where the user is active

since you're using UNION and not UNION ALL, you are implicitly asking for a SELECT DISTINCT, but the fields are different (it makes no sense to display newsid and then post_time in the same field)
*plus, you have a typo in the field name, which is not **news_id***

---

You have to look at it from the other way around. The potential combinations amount for a scenario where every user has read every new. So you get that universe as a basis (number of users times number of news) and then

1- remove inactive users

2- remove news older than 30 days

3- remove tuples that are unrelated in the `news_viewed` table

```
SELECT users.username, news.newsid
FROM users
JOIN news 
   ON users.status='active'  -- removes inactive users
   AND news.post_time>'$_30daysago' -- removes older news
LEFT JOIN 
   news_viewed nv USING (username, newsid) 
WHERE nv.nvid IS NULL -- removes unrelated entries
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating this has helped me to understand better what I was doing wrong.