# MySQL JOIN: Only return rows where all values from right table are NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two MySQL tables like this:

```
orders:
+----------+------+
| order_id | name |
+----------+------+
| 1        | Mary |
| 2        | John |
| 3        | Anne |
+----------+------+

order_details:
+----------+----------------+
| order_id | shipped        |
+----------+----------------+
| 1        | null           |
| 1        | null           |
| 1        | SHIPPED-123ABC |
| 2        | null           |
| 2        | null           |
| 3        | SHIPPED-XYZ    |
| 3        | SHIPPED-XYZ    |
| 3        | null           |
+----------+----------------+
```

Now I want to join the order_details-table to the orders-table but only show the entries that only  have NULL shipped values in the order_details table. So in this example only order_id #2 would get returned.

So the result would be:

```
+----------+------+---------+
| order_id | name | shipped |
+----------+------+---------+
| 2        | John | null    |
+----------+------+---------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: What's the PRIMARY KEY on the order_details table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL select rows where left join is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890534/mysql-select-rows-where-left-join-is-null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select o.order_id, o.name, null as shipped 
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 
                  from order_details od 
                   where od.order_id = o.order_id and od.shipped is not null
                 );
```

Simple aggregation with `JOIN` would also work :

```
select o.order_id, o.name, null as shipped
from orders o inner join
     order_details od
     on od.order_id = o.order_id
group by o.order_id, o.name
having min(od.shipped) = max(od.shipped) and min(od.shipped) is null;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want orders that have at least *one* row in `order_details`, then use aggregation:

```
select o.*
from (select od.order_id
      from order_details 
      group by od.order_id
      having count(shipped) = 0
     ) od join
     orders o
     on od.order_id = o.order_id;
```

If you want *all* such orders, even those with no rows in `order_details`, then use `not exists`:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1
                  from order_details od
                  where od.order_id = o.order_id and
                        od.shipping is not null
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether below query gives what you want.

```
SELECT
  o.order_id,
  o.name,
  od.shipped
FROM
  orders o
  INNER JOIN order_details od ON od.order_id = o.order_id
WHERE
  od.shipped IS NULL
  AND od.shipped NOT IN     
(
SELECT od.shipped
WHERE
    od.shipped IS NOT NULL
     )
```